# Couldn't derive type

Tags: scala, generics, couchdb

I'm using Scala and CouchDB and have created a generic `save` method to store my objects in the database. Because it is generic it can't compile the code.

My generic `save` method looks like:

```
abstract class AbstractRepository[T] extends LazyLogging {
  private val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  private val hostname: String = config.getString("couchdb.hostname")
  private val port: Int = config.getInt("couchdb.port")

  val couch = CouchDb(hostname, port)
  val mapping: TypeMapping
  val db: CouchDbApi

  def save(item: T): Unit = {
    db.docs.create(item)
  }
}
```

`AbstractRepository` gets extended by `SummonerRepository`:

```
class SummonerRepository extends AbstractRepository[Summoner] {
  val mapping = TypeMapping(classOf[Summoner] -> "Summoner")
  val db = couch.db("summoner-db", mapping)
}
```

When I try to compile this I get this error:

> Error:(24, 34) Couldn't derive type T
>       db.docs.create(item)

I don't understand why this cannot be derived. Why is this and is there a way around this error?

**Edit:** When I cast the type to `Summoner` it works flawlessly, but that's no use as it won't be generic anymore:

```
def save(item: T): Unit = {
        db.docs.create(item.asInstanceOf[Summoner])
      }
```

Comment: From the plain Scala point of view, everything is OK (that is, having a method with a generic parameter defined as abstract class type parameter and instantiating that with concrete type value). The error message looks unfamiliar to me though so I googled it up and found nothing; just a couple of irrelevant problems with the same message that had errors due to filename clashes or case classes with >21 fields. So I think it could be a CouchDB thing. What kind of parameter does `db.docs.create` take? Surely it cannot take some generic `T` type defined in the outer scope.

Comment: Does `db.docs.create[T](item)` work?

Comment: @ipoteka That did not work unfortunately

Comment: @slouc `def create[D: W](obj: D): Task[Res.DocOk]` By the looks of it it takes a generic object

Comment: Ok but not any generic object. It takes a D for which W[D]  exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing, can you rename your class Summoner for $Summoner and test again. The code for couchdb-scala tries to get the name using *getCanonicalName* and it throws an *java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name*. Amazing.. isn´t it?